# Why is 'Windows Network' showing up when I don't use one?

Tags: networking, 20.04, windows

I have an Asus laptop running Ubuntu 20.04 and get my internet from my mobile. I went to 'other places' to see what was there (in the folder manager) and saw that 'Windows Network' is listed. I cannot go into it as when I click on it I get an error message. This is a fresh install of Ubuntu 20.04 and it has only ever connected to my phone. I don't have Wine installed either.

Should I be worried or is this normal?

Comment: Think it just a naming confection, like Ubuntu 64bit is called AMD64.

Comment: Think it is for sharing data between different machines by the network, instead of having to use a USB stick.